# How to remove hyperlink from sharepoint calendar web part event

Tags: 2013, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a Calendar View web part that I've placed in a SharePoint page. When I create an item to SharePoint calendar list. Item is shown as an hyperlink.

Any idea how to hide/remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onsuccess handler of the calendar.

```
SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed
```

Add something like below to the success handler

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(removeCalendarLinks, "sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js");

// call the below function or append to onsuccess handler
function removeCalendarLinks() {
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.ms-acal-mdiv a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;')
        $(this).attr('href', '#');
    });
 });
}
```

See a similar example here: https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/handle-clicks-on-calendar-items-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript/

The article is for SP 2010 but the concept should be similar for 2013.